# How to change time zone setting inside create view code

Tags: sql, teradata, rdbms, teradatasql

Do you know if there is a way to write "set time zone interval '00:00' hour to minute" inside create view code? I`ve been finding ways on how to do it because I cannot change the default time zone setting of a user or ask him to change the current time zone setting every time he select a view table.

Comment: Is the column a TIMESTAMP or a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE? Did you try `timestamp_column at 0`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Show the original time zone?

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, column is just TIMESTAMP. I just tried `timestamp_column at 0` but it did not work. Fortunately, I do no longer need to change the time zone setting of my view now. Always thank you for your comment!

Comment: Hi @Andrew, I am trying to change the time zone setting from the View to be able to display the result of `expand on anchor month_end` function correctly yet it seems impossible. Fortunately, I found out that I do not need to do it because I can specify a time literals for month_end instead.